# Remove "unnecessary" spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I would like to remove all the "unnecessary" spaces from a string. Specifically:

```
"a b c d" => "a b c d" // spaces between two words are left in
" a b c d " => "a b c d" // spaces not between two words are removed
"a  b c   d" => "a b c d" // as are duplicate spaces
```

Is there any regex out there that I can put into `String.replace()` to do this for me?

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `trim()` to remove spaces at the ends of the strings, and regexp replacement to replace multiple spaces in the middle.

```
str = str.trim().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `split`, `filter` and `join`. This will split the string, filter out the extra empty array entries then rejoin them with a space:

```
variable.split(" ").filter(Boolean).join(" ");
```

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you for the answer, but I should have thought of that myself :)

Comment: @Qix Performance was not among the requirements that OP stated. It it obviously important to **you**, but to show how the problem can be solved this is still the most *human readable* way to do it. As long as performance does not become an issue, I'd prefer this alot over your favored solution.

Comment: @connexo [Performance is a feature.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/performance-is-a-feature/) It should be a consideration in everything you do coding-wise. Always. It might be a cute one-liner, but the fact is is that it's non-performant and incredibly obtuse.

Comment: @Qix Performance is a feature, but if the gains from performance are marginal (as they most likely are in this case) readability is favorable. [Readability vs Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709334/readability-vs-performance)

Comment: @asdf `String.replace` is incredibly readable - it's one function call vs. three. As well, this answer is **5x slower** than the other answers. I understand the necessity of readability, but in this case it's a no brainer.

Comment: @connexo "this is still the most human readable way to do it" --- well, it's far from readability and semantic: the question is about removing (replacing) substrings from a string, not about splitting a string into chunks. I honestly don't believe someone would find `"foo".replace` code less readable than this.

Comment: So readability in JS code does in your opinion involve knowledge about regex syntax? I do recognize the power in regular expressions - and that was actually what OP asked for - but I wouldn't exactly consider regexes as human readable.

Comment: @connexo it's more about `String.prototype.replace` semantics. It clearly addresses the operation to be performed: to replace a substring with another substring. And yes, I believe understanding `/\s{2,}/g` is a strong "must" requirement for a developer. And yes, I find this regex trivial and 101 of regexes.

Comment: @connexo regexes are neither readable nor unreadable. The official Email regex is unreadable; `\s+` is readable. If you don't know regex, you're going to have a hard time with Javascript since it's heavily used.

Answer (score 3):

This should work in ES 3 enabled browsers as well.

```
function deleteUnwantedWhitespace (searchstring) {
   searchstring = searchstring.trim().split(" ");
   var tempArray = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < searchstring.length; i++) {
      if (searchstring[i]) {
          tempArray.push(searchstring[i]);
      }
   }
   return tempArray.join(" ");
}
```

Edit: I just learned that `String.prototype.trim` is part of ES 5.1, so here's the polyfill:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
  };
}
```

Comment: This is the fastest ES3-compatible solution.

Comment: What clients does the ES3-compliance address? Curious what makes one deliberately limit themselves without (?) a good reason.

Comment: It addresses IE8, which is still important in many company environments, as sad as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Do it manually

```
var strArr = ["a b c d", " a b c d ", "a  b c   d"];

for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
  console.log(removeSpaces(strArr[i]));
}

function removeSpaces(str) {
  str = str.replace(/ +/g, ' ');
  str = str.trim();

  return str;
}
```

Comment: Just a note, you don't need code snippets just to have a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly possible. The first regex replaces 1 or more `\s` characters with a single space. This includes spaces, tabs, and new-lines.

```
str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

If you just want spaces, use

```
str.replace(/ +/g, ' ');
```

This is also [more than 5x faster](http://jsperf.com/extraneous-spaces) than using a `Boolean` filter.